# Problem showing correct HBase date type in Apache Phoenix

Tags: java, date, timestamp, hbase, apache-phoenix

I got problem while reading date format data which created through hbase api (using 'put' command) from apache phoenix.

This is the date format what i expected : 
Date : 2018-12-17T21:21:45+07:00 into 
'yyyy-MM-dd' => '2018-12-17'

The table is created from phoenix client using below DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"
(
 ID VARCHAR,
 "col1".TRX_DATES UNSIGNED_DATE 
 CONSTRAINT PKD PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

But, when i'm trying to query the data, it shows incorrect date format :

> 292269006-11-18

I've tried some research and experiment using various data type to insert date to hbase, include using long value (milliseconds)  of the date. But still, it cannot show the correct date value in phoenix ('yyyy-MM-dd')

Any suggestions for this case?

Comment: it should be '2018-12-17' in phoenix table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should have been a comment because I cannot explain all the details of what has gone wrong nor how you can fix it. But I can see that your problem comes from an inversion of the sign bit of the milliseconds since the epoch. I tried this:

```
    long milli = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-12-17T21:21:45+07:00").toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    milli += Long.MIN_VALUE; // Flip the sign bit
    Date wrongDateAsOldfashiondDate = new Date(milli);
    System.out.println(wrongDateAsOldfashiondDate);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(wrongDateAsOldfashiondDate));
```

The output on my computer (in Europe/Copenhagen time zone) was:

> ```
> Fri Nov 18 08:08:49 CET 292269006
> 292269006-11-18
> ```

Normally one shouldn’t use the old and poorly designed `Date` class, but this was the way I could get exactly the same result as yours. The difference from the modern date and time API is that `Date` uses the Julian calendar, so apparently this was also used by the software giving your unexpected result (probably the `Date` class was involved there too).

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Frankly I would wait a couple of days before doing that. Questions that don’t have an accepted answer tend to get more attention, and I should say that there’s a fine chance that someone can provide more information than I do in my answer. Of course accepting an answer eventually is good style (you an unaccept now and accept again later).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I finally solved the problem. That's true, seems like the software use the old fashioned date to format the result. My solution is just parse the long mili value to hbase, so phoenix can format it correctly.